# Facebook: Custom tab for people pages

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to create a custom tab with an iFrame in it from a remote server for a people page? So not a company, but a person?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, profile tabs were disabled as part of the [November 2010 profile changes](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/425/).